# Value/Cost of numbers from average intervals

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, optimization, algorithms

I've been working on this problem for a while, and cannot think of an elegant solution. This is a simple example. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Numbers are evenly distributed in the interval $[0, 1]$. $5$ of these numbers can be averaged to score points. If the average of the $5$ numbers is less than $0.5$, $2$ points are scored. Otherwise, $1$ point is scored.

I am investigating the relative 'value' of these numbers. Ie, how much more useful $0.1$ is than $0.9$ (clearly an average under $0.5$ can be formed more easily with $0.1$).

I believe it follows $0.4$ is at least twice as good as $1$ for scoring points - since $0.4$ s can be averaged for $2$ points rather than $1$. I am trying to answer the general case of how much more useful one number is than another.

Any help formulating this problem more formally would be great.

Thanks very much

Comment: I do not see why you would want to assign a "profit value" to a number nor how you would use it in any consistent way. The question makes no sense.

Comment: A minor quibble: near the start of the question you say that if the average of the five numbers is less than $0.5,$ the profit is $1.$ But later you take five numbers whose average is $0.4$ and say the profit is $2,$ contradicting the earlier rule. (Note that even if you fix this inconsistency, the question still makes no sense.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the question's phrasing. Is that more clear?

Comment: OK, the edit changes my opinion about the question. Previously it was unanswerable; now it presents what I think is a bad idea, but at least it is clear and consistent enough that I can _explain_ why I think it's a bad idea. That makes it a reasonable question, and I have tried to answer it.

Comment: I think this should be construed as "How many points is it worth paying to get a particular number as one of the five?".

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's the approach I took. It actually works OK for "buying" one number and allowing the other four to be picked randomly. Maybe that's enough; I interpreted the question as looking for something where the value of two $0.4$s is twice the value of one $0.4,$ but perhaps this was an overinterpretation on my part.

Comment: I've responded to the answer further down, thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me formalize and generalize the problem. You have a sequence of $n$
random variables, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n,$ such that $X_i \sim U[0,1]$ for each $i.$ Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$
That is, $X$ is a *uniform sum distribution* with parameter $n.$

Then the number of points scored is $1 + Y,$ where
$$
 Y =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } X < n/2,
\\ 
0 & \text{if } X \geq n/2.
\end{cases}
$$

That is, $Y=1$ if the mean of the $n$ uniform random variables is less than $\frac12,$ and $Y=0$ otherwise.

In order to keep the discussion relatively simple, I'll assume the values of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are revealed one at a time, and that the "point value" of a number $q$ at any given time is the amount you should be willing to "pay" in order to replace the next random variable with the number $q.$

You can also apply formulas based on this interpretation to a situation in which you have some kind of opportunity to choose the values of one or more of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ and then allow the remaining variables to be assigned randomly.

Now suppose the values of $h$ of the variables are known
(already randomly revealed or chosen by you), that is,
we know that $X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_h = x_h,$
and suppose you have the opportunity to set an additional $k$ variables
to a certain sequence of values,
$X_{h+1} = x_{h+1}, \ldots, X_{h+k} = x_{h+k}.$
The "point value" of the sequence $(x_{h+1}, \ldots, x_{h+k})$
under those conditions is the difference between the expected value of $1+Y$ given that all $h+k$ of these variables are known to have the specified values and the expected value of $1+Y$ given only the first $h$ variables.
But the (conditional) expected value of $1+Y$ is just $1$ plus the (conditional) expected value of $Y$, so
\begin{multline}
V(x_{h+1}, \ldots, x_{h+k}) =
E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1 \land \cdots\land X_{h+k} = x_{h+k}) \\
 - E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1 \land \cdots\land X_h = x_h)
\end{multline}
In other words, the point value of the $k$ additional numbers is the amount by which we increase the conditional expectation of $Y$ when we include those $k$ numbers in the condition.

For example, with $h=0$ and $k=1$ we are assessing the point value of choosing the value of $X_1$ before any of the values are known.
The point value of the numerical value $x_1$ in those circumstances is
$$ V(x_1) = E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1 ) - E(Y) . $$

The conditional expectation $E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1)$ is the probability that after the remaining $n-1$ variables are chosen randomly, the total
(including $x_1$) will not exceed $n/2$; that is,
$$ E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1) = P\left(X_2+\cdots+X_n < \frac n2 - x_1\right).$$

The probability on the right-hand side depends on a uniform sum distribution with parameter $n-1.$
For convenience, let $F_m$ be the cumulative distribution function of
a uniform sum distribution with parameter $m.$
Then
$$
P\left(X_2+\cdots+X_n < \frac n2 - x_1\right) 
= F_{n-1}\left(\frac n2 - x_1\right).
$$
Of course 
$$E(Y) = P\left(X_1+\cdots+X_n < \frac n2\right)
 = F_n\left(\frac n2\right) = 0.5.$$

The following table gives some approximate values of this probability when $n=5$ (as in the original question):

\begin{array}{lc}
x_1 & E(Y \mid X_1 = x_1) \\
0   & 0.7995\\
0.2 & 0.6920\\
0.4 & 0.5663\\
0.5 & 0.5000\\
0.6 & 0.4337\\
0.8 & 0.3080\\
1   & 0.2005\\
\end{array}

That is, in these circumstances the point value of $0$ is approximately $0.2995$ and the point value of $1$ is approximately $-0.2995,$
that is, we should desire to be paid at least $0.2995$ before we would be willing to choose to set $X_1 = 1.$

Going back to the general case in which $h$ variables have already been set
to the values $x_1, \ldots, x_h,$ we can show that
$$
V(x_{h+1}, \ldots, x_{h+k}) =
F_{n-h-k}\left(\frac n2 - (x_1 + \cdots + x_{h+k})\right)
 - F_{n-h}\left(\frac n2 - (x_1 + \cdots + x_h)\right).
$$

This is a general formula covering all cases of this kind;
the fly in the ointment is that the formula for $F_m$ can be a bit
annoying to work with. For the first few uniform sum distributions,
the cumulative probability functions are:

\begin{align}
F_1(x) &= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x<0,\\
x & \text{if }0\leq x\leq 1, \\
1 & \text{if }x > 1,
\end{cases} \\
F_2(x) &= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x<0,\\
\frac12x^2 & \text{if }0\leq x<1,\\
1 - \frac12 (2 - x)^2 & \text{if }1\leq x\leq 2,\\
1 & \text{if }x > 2,
\end{cases} \\
F_3(x) &= \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } x<0,\\
\frac16x^3 & \text{if } 0\leq x<1,\\
-\frac13 x^3 + \frac32 x^2 - \frac32 x + \frac12 & \text{if } 1\leq x<2,\\
1 - \frac16 (3 - x)^3 & \text{if } 2\leq x\leq 3,\\
1 & \text{if }x>3,
\end{cases} \\
F_4(x) &= \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } x<0,\\
\frac{1}{24}x^4 & \text{if } 0\leq x<1,\\
-\frac18 x^4 + \frac23 x^3 - x^2 + \frac23 x - \frac16 
& \text{if } 1\leq x<2,\\
\frac18 (4 - x)^4 - \frac23 (4 - x)^3 + (4 - x)^2 - \frac23 (4 - x) + \frac76 
& \text{if } 2\leq x<3,\\
1 - \frac{1}{24} (4 - x)^4 & \text{if } 3\leq x\leq 4,\\
1 & \text{if } x > 4.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

(Source: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=uniform+sum+distribution+with+n%3D4).)

Comment: Not an overinterpretation. Very interesting answer. In my case, i am looking for: "How many points is it worth paying to get a particular number as one of the five?" (as another commenter said) and to then extent that question to: "How many points is it worth paying to get a particular number as one of the 4 remaining random numbers?" (once one has already been selected by the previous question). I would consider those 2 questions separate. Im looking for the function which maps real numbers $[0, 1]$ to "the number of dollars" which could be payed for them, in the context of either question.

Comment: OK, I think I get the question now. I have updated the answer to give general formulas for calculating the "number of dollars" in each case.

Comment: That answers the question perfectly, thanks. I've extended the question, hopefully in a clear way, in a separate thread (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379477/buying-cards-to-create-complete-sets-for-points) can you see how the two link together? Thanks again